# Liquids flows to weird direction. (It flows toward one area of the domain object)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image: Li]

I'm doing some assignment with Blender to use physics simulation, and I found my fluids are flowing to a weird direction. The fluid was supposed to flow downward, because that is how it usually works, and it worked so before an hour ago. Somehow I may changed some setting but I can't find what changed it's behavior.

I tested with other quick liquid domains and their fluids goes into same direction too.

Here are my domain setting. I also checked the scene Gravity setting, but it's not touched. (-9.81 m/s2 for Z-gravity)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found what was the problem.

I found that the Wind Force Field I had at the outside the domain was affecting the whole scene! This is the first time I'm using the Force field and I didn't know it could affect the whole scene.